# Using CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX with exported targets

Tags: cmake

When I use `set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "d")`, the build and install targets work as expected. But in the `libfooTargets-debug.cmake` file with the exported targets, there is a path to `libfoo` and not `libfood`.

I exported the targets like this:

```
install(TARGETS libfoo EXPORT libfoo-targets LIBRARY DESTINATION lib ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
install(EXPORT libfoo-targets FILE libfooTargets.cmake DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
```

which creates and installs `libfooTargets.cmake` and `libfooTargets-debug.cmake` when building in debug mode, and `libfooTargets.cmake` and `libfooTargets-release.cmake` when building in release mode.

Both `libfooTargets-release.cmake` and `libfooTargets-debug.cmake` reference the name without a postfix as:

```
list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_libfoo "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/libfoo.lib" )
```

and thus a program linking against the debug target still uses the release-build library and I would need to install release and debug versions into different folders to be able to link against the debug target.

How can I get the exported targets to work with a debug postfix?

---

I could of course try to change the library name depending on `CMAKE_RELEASE_TYPE` or a `CONFIGURATION` generator expression, but this will probably break the multi-configuration features in MSVC and other IDEs supporting different targets and seems not to work in the sense of how the exported targets feature is meant to simplify and unify the build.

I suspect that the `install(EXPORT ...)` command somehow drops the `CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX` or does not implement it for generating the `libfooTargets-{release,debug}.cmake` files, but possibly I overlooked how to make this variable visible to the generator of the exported targets or something like this.

---

All target code

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11.1)
project(foo)
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)
set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "d")

# ...

add_library(libfoo STATIC somesource.cpp someheader.h)
target_include_directories(libfoo PUBLIC
         $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
)
target_link_libraries(libfoo
        somelibrary
)
target_include_directories (libfoo PUBLIC
        somelibrary_header_dirs
)
install(TARGETS libfoo EXPORT libfoo-targets LIBRARY DESTINATION lib ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
install(EXPORT libfoo-targets FILE libfooTargets.cmake DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})

configure_package_config_file(libfooConfig.cmake.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libfooConfig.cmake INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libfooConfig.cmake DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
install(DIRECTORY include/ DESTINATION include FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")
```

The platform is a Windows 10 with cmake 3.11.1 and MSVC 2015. Of course the most general solution is probably the best one.

Comment: Can you share your CMake `add_library` command and all other command(s) you used for the target in question? I usually specify `CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX` on every target I build and haven't had any problems doing so and later exporting those targets.

Comment: I added the ``add_library`` and ``target_...`` commands.

Comment: I don't see anything different from my version. Try to set the CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX variable shortly after the Project command, as this command may overwrite some of your previous settings. On what platform are you experiencing the behaviour? I'm on Windows with MSVC and do not see it. But the documentations states `This property is ignored on the Mac for Frameworks and App Bundles.`

Comment: I added the head of the file to the post.

Comment: I moved the line before the package config helper include, now it works. I moved it back to verify and it still works. I am not sure what happened (and if it will work reliable), so I keep the line before the include.

Comment: Again the question, on which platform using which CMake version are you experiencing this behaviour?

Comment: Windows 10 with MSVC 2015 and CMake 3.11.1

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the [`install`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) command, you need to reference the configuration that you are interested in:

> [...] If a CONFIGURATIONS option is given then the file will only be installed when one of the named configurations is installed. Additionally, the generated import file will reference only the matching target configurations. [...]

So, you need to add the `CONFIGURATIONS` option in both `install` commands and duplicate the commands for each configuration you want to install and export.

Comment: I do not explicitly generate configurations with cmake as this project is used with MSVC, which has its own way to choose debug or release mode. This works for the postfix, but the generated targets are wrong, even when it seems to get the configuration (as it generates as ``-debug.cmake`` file). I am not sure what I should set with a ``CONFIGURATIONS`` option to make it work.

Comment: @allo Unfortunately, I'm not on windows. The doc doesn't mention specific handling for tools that can generate multiple configurations per build. This might direct MSVC appropriately. Why don't you try to add `CONFIGURATIONS Debug` at those commands?

Comment: Because cmake generates an unified msvc project, where you can switch between Debug and Release configurations without running cmake, if you do not specify anything. Using CMake parameters would be easy, then I could change the library name depending on ``CMAKE_RELEASE_TYPE``. But this would not generate a multi-configuration msvc project file. I am suspecting that the cmake exported targets system does not respect ``CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX`` at all.

Comment: @allo, I see. I did some digging in CMake's mailing list and bug tracker and I found this [thread](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-July/055360.html) and this [bug](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14317) marked as resolved. They seem relevant and report the issue resolved in CMake 3.3.